# Tables not found in imported Sqlite Database on xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am running into a problem with SQLite where I imported a database from the assets folder into forms, now I'm trying to load the database using the method given by Microsoft, but now when I am loading it shows the tablemappings don't exist.

I know this because if I set a breakpoint on the bit where it checks the tablemappings, all I'm given is the table mappings to the database file that is created in the app.

I once managed to get it to load one of the databases and it told me that it cannot write to a readonly database, so it was trying to create a new table (I honestly do not know how it happened or how to recreate it, because changed the code back and it doesnt reproduce)

The error actually thrown is a "NullRefrenceException: loading...", but I'm 90% sure I am getting this one since the initializer is an async task. Anyway I have polly to try and rerun the initializer after it should have fully initialized (A solution that works fantastically with my main database, that is created on device)
When I continue past it everything just freezes.

I used the profiler and after a bit it did save the model, it also show loads of nullrefrenceexceptions but basically it just ignores not loading the database.

Honestly I'm sitting here for hours trying different things, and can't seem to find a solution, I tried looking for a few hours as well online...

DataBase

```
private async Task Initialize()
        {
            _db = await GetDatabaseConnection<SabbathModel>();
        }

static readonly Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection> _lazyInitializer = new Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection>(() =>
        {
            return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.InternalDatabasePath, Constants.InternalDBFlags);
        });

        static SQLiteAsyncConnection DB => _lazyInitializer.Value;
        public static bool initialized = false;

        protected static async Task<SQLiteAsyncConnection> GetDatabaseConnection<T>()
        {
            if (!initialized)
            {
                if (!DB.TableMappings.Any(x => x.MappedType == typeof(T)))
                {
                    await DB.CreateTablesAsync(CreateFlags.None, typeof(T)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                
                initialized = true;
            }
            return DB;
        }
```

Constants Mentioned:

```
public static string InternalDatabasePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            return Path.Combine(basePath, InternalDatabaseFilename);
        }
    }

public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags InternalDBFlags =
        // open the database in read/write mode
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadOnly |
        // enable multi-threaded database access
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.PrivateCache;

public const string InternalDatabaseFilename = "InternalDatabase.db3";
```

and the task that loads the database on the phone

```
private async Task CopyInternalDataBase()
        {
            string dbPath = Constants.InternalDatabasePath;
            if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
            {
                using BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("InternalDataBase.db"));
                using BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.Create));

                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int len = 0;
                while ((len = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    bw.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: is this Android or iOS?  Where does `OpenAppPackageFileAsync` come from?

Comment: It is coming from Android

Comment: You should add the `.db` file into the `Assets` folder in the Android project and mark the `Build Action` as `AndroidAsset` to use it with `OpenAppPackageFileAsync`.

Comment: Sorry I was going to say as well I checked that the file exists with System.IO.File.Exists() The file Is there, I also opened it with an online sql IDE and confirmed the Table name and the table header on the model are the same, anyway its showing me none of the tables exist

Comment: Literally changed nothing, works fine now... 

I think when it pushed forward and gave me all the null exceptions it was beacuse the query wasn't giving me any result since it was faulty, why it completely froze i don't know just started working now...